# How to keep controls from stretching when window resize

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with Buttons, a DataGrid and a TreeView. All of my controls are in one Grid.

```
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ColumnDefinition Width="193"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="839"/>


    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="138"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

In the grid I have:

3 ComboBoxes 
1 TreeView
2 TextBoxes

The problem I have is that, every time I stretch my Window, the controls expand with the Window. However they are each different shapes and this creates an awkward visual result. How can I keep them where they are?

Comment: 6 control in 4 cells.  In question you want to keep them where they are but in comment you want them to expand with the window.  Sooo unclear.

Comment: Why my question down voted? would be nice if you comment when down voting it will help the userto learn from making the same mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out a way to solve this. I made a grid which has 4 column and 3 rows

```
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you've got 6 controls into 4 grid cells, but either way use [fixed width columns and rows](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html), e.g:

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
```

Comment: that works fine but how can I make al the controls not overlap with each other but expand with the window? EX: in visual studio when we expand and restore other controls stay in shape but expand with the window

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you should use the appropriate width type - Auto, fixed, or percentage depending on how you want the grid panel to react. Then assign a grid row and column to your other controls to specify where they sit in the grid.